# Create Always On VM With No WAN Connection

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I know how to use `Virtualbox` to create a virtual machine, but have never used it for anything more than testing.  How can I use `Virtualbox` to:

> 1) Share Drives with host computer
>   2) Have LAN Connection but no WAN connection
>   3) Always be on

**EDIT**
I want to be able to access the host computers drives from the VM and access the VM drives from the host computer.

I want to be able to access the VM from within my local network but not allow the VM to have internet (outside my network) access

Always have the VM "Powered On"

Comment: You need to explain in further detail what exactly you are aiming to achieve. We can't help you if you don't tell us more.

Comment: You could either not give the VM a gateway (can't get off the local subnet) or put an ACL in the router to prevent packets from that address getting to the WAN.

Comment: Use a firewall.

Comment: @RonMaupin - That's a great solution.  How would I set it up to share drives?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a network guy, not a VM guy, but I would assume that the VM looks just like another host/server on the network, and other hosts could map share to it like any other host/server.